How to display updated data without refreshing the page?
I'm creating an update function with React:
function Company(props) {
    const { contact, company, companies, setCompanies } = props;
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
    const [editedName, setEditedName] = useState(company.company_name);
    const [editedAddress, setEditedAddress] = useState(company.company_address);

    async function deleteCompany() {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/contacts/${contact.id}/companies/${company.company_id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            let newCompanies = companies.filter(c => c.company_id !== company.company_id);
            setCompanies(newCompanies); // Update companies list
        }
    }

    async function updateCompany(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/contacts/${contact.id}/companies/${company.company_id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                company_name: editedName,
                company_address: editedAddress
            })
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const updatedCompany = await response.json();

            // Update the company in the companies array
            const updatedCompanies = companies.map(c =>
                c.company_id === updatedCompany.company_id ? updatedCompany : c
            );
            setCompanies(updatedCompanies); // Trigger re-render by updating state
            setIsEditing(false); // Exit editing mode
        }
    }

and the way it return:
 return (
        <tr>
            {isEditing ? (
                <>
                    <td>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={editedName}
                            onChange={(e) => setEditedName(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            value={editedAddress}
                            onChange={(e) => setEditedAddress(e.target.value)}
                        />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="button green" onClick={updateCompany}>Save</button>
                        <button className="button red" onClick={() => setIsEditing(false)}>Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </>
            ) : (
                <>
                    <td>{company.company_name}</td>
                    <td>{company.company_address}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button className="button green" onClick={() => setIsEditing(true)}>Edit</button>
                        <button className="button red" onClick={deleteCompany}>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </>
            )}
        </tr>
    );
}

What I trying to do is that, when I update, the new data will immediately show up, but it did not. It only shows up when I refresh the page. This only happens with updateCompany(), deleteCompany() works well (the company data disappears right away when I click on delete button).

You need to check following on your updateCompany function:

if response.ok is actually triggered
if updatedCompany actually returns something,
if updatedCompanies gives right result,
else setError to right error from backend

async function updateCompany(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/api/contacts/${contact.id}/companies/${company.company_id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                company_name: editedName,
                company_address: editedAddress,
            }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Failed to update company: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
        }

        const updatedCompany = await response.json();

        if (!updatedCompany || !updatedCompany.company_id) {
            throw new Error('Invalid data received from server');
        }

        // Update the company in the state
        const updatedCompanies = companies.map((c) =>
            c.company_id === updatedCompany.company_id ? updatedCompany : c
        );
        setCompanies(updatedCompanies); 
        setIsEditing(false); 

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error updating company:', error);
        alert(`An error occurred while updating the company: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

As a bonus, it is always good to use try/catch.

Thank you, So when I applied your code,  It returned An error occurred while updating the company: Invalid data received from server. Does  that mean something wrong with my controller file?

Haha, Thank you again . It is really because of my controller file as I only return message in the update  route. Thank you so much.

@Trinhvanhuy that explains the problem indeed, hope it helped. If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted so others don't invest more time on it.
